# Select multiple rows from table and join as CSV

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Lets say I've got two tables:

```
album
    album_id
    album_name
```

and

```
song
    album_id
    song_name
    track_number
```

and I'd like to create a SQL query which, given an `album_id`, will return the `album_name` in one field and all the `song_name`s in a comma separated list, ordered by `track_number` in another field.

The end result would be a cursor with one row, two columns:

> album_name : "Some Album Name"
>
> songs: "song1, song2, song3, song4"

I think I need something like this:

```
SELECT a.*,  group_concat(s.name ORDERBY s.track_number SEPERATOR ', ')
FROM album a
LEFT JOIN songs s
WHERE (a.album_id=1)
```

This is wrong but I think I'm on the right lines

Is this possible in sqlite3 on Android?  Can you tell me how?

** EDIT **
Following on from ypercube's excellent answer, which works, is there a way to add another field, much like song but lets call it musician.

So the new table is

```
musician
    album_id
    musician_name
    musician_number
```

and my cursor would now give me a result of :

> album_name : "Some Album Name"
>
> songs: "song1, song2, song3, song4"
>
> musician: "musician1, musician2, musician3"

with the musician value sorted on the musician_number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can choose order in sqlite's `GROUP_CONCAT()`, only separator. See the **[`Aggregate functions in SQLite`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)**:

```
SELECT a.*
     , group_concat(s.name, ', ')
FROM album a
  LEFT JOIN songs s
    ON s.album_id = a.album_id
WHERE a.album_id = 1       --- skip this line for all the albums to be displayed
GROUP BY a.album_id
```

or this to (hopefully) get the order you want:

```
SELECT a.*
     , song_list
FROM a
  INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT album_id
           , group_concat(name, ', ') song_list
      FROM
        ( SELECT a.album_id
               , s.name
          FROM a 
            LEFT JOIN songs s
              ON s.album_id = a.album_id
          WHERE a.album_id = 1      
          ORDER BY a.album_id
                 , s.track_number
        ) g
      GROUP BY a.album_id
    ) grp
    ON grp.album_id = a.album_id
```

---

If you have another table to group_concat:

```
SELECT a.*
     , song_list
     , artist_list
FROM a
  INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT album_id
           , group_concat(name, ', ') song_list
      FROM
        ( SELECT a.album_id
               , s.name
          FROM a 
            LEFT JOIN songs s
              ON s.album_id = a.album_id
      --- WHERE a.album_id = 1      
          ORDER BY a.album_id
                 , s.track_number
        ) g
      GROUP BY a.album_id
    ) grp
    ON grp.album_id = a.album_id
  INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT album_id
           , group_concat(artist_name, ', ') artist_list
      FROM
        ( SELECT a.album_id
               , r.artist_name
          FROM a 
            LEFT JOIN artists r
              ON r.album_id = a.album_id
      --- WHERE a.album_id = 1      
          ORDER BY a.album_id
                 , r.artist_order
        ) g2
      GROUP BY a.album_id
    ) grp2
    ON grp2.album_id = a.album_id
```

Comment: Awesome - this works great.  thank you.  Is there an easy way to add columns to this?  say I wanted a similar thing with artist_name as i did song_name, given an addition table of [album_id, artist_name, artist_order]

Comment: Isn't the artist info stored in the `album` table?

Comment: yeah, so my end result would now be "album name", "song 1, song 2, song 3", "artist 1, artist 2, artist 3" etc.  I'll update the question

Comment: Have updated the question - used musician instead of artist to avoid some confusion.

Comment: Slightly changed the answer. So you can add another similar subquery.

Comment: Thank you x 10000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

You can't do so directly but you can fetch the desired fields via a regular query of the like `select album_name, song_name from album natural join song ... ...` and then iterate the resultset with your cursor to build a comma separated string. When you finish building the CSstring you can write it on a CSV file.

Comment: Ah, don't actually want a CSV file - I want a cursor which has two columns - one with the album name and one with all the song titles, separated by commas.  I think i need to use a group_concat function - any ideas?